# Filter on a nested aggregate SUM function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these two tables (the names have been pluralized for the sake of the example):

Table `Locations`:

```
idlocation varchar(12)
name       varchar(50)
```

Table `Answers`:

```
idlocation varchar(6)
question_number varchar(3)
answer_text1    varchar(300)
answer_text2    varchar(300)
```

This table can hold answers for multiple locations according a list of numbered questions that repeat on each of them.

What I am trying to do is to add up the values residing in the `answer_text1` and `answer_text2` columns, for each location available on the Locations table but for **only** an specific question and then output a value based on the result (1 or 0).

The query goes as follows using a nested table Answers to perform the SUM operation:

```
select
l.idlocation,    

'RESULT' = (
              case when (
                select 
                sum(cast(isnull(c.answer_text1,0) as int)) +
                sum(cast(isnull(c.answer_text2,0) as int)) 
                from Answers c
                where b.idlocation=c.idlocation and c.question_number='05'
              ) > 0 then
                           1
              else 
                           0
              end
            ) 

from Locations l, Answers b
where l.idlocation=b.idlocation and b.question_number='05'
```

In the table `Answers` I am saving sometimes a date string type of value for its field `answer_text2` but on a different question number.

When I run the query I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '27/12/2013' to data type int

I do have that value `'27/12/2013'` on the `answer_text2` field but for a different question, so my filter gets ignored on the nested select statement after this: `b.idlocation=c.idlocation`, and it's adding up apparently **more questions** hence the error posted.

**Update**

According to Steve's suggested solution, I ended up implementing the filter to avoid char/varchar considerations into my SUM statement with a little variant:

Every possible not INT string value has a length greater than 2 ('00' to '99' for my question numbers) so I use this filter to determine when I am going to apply the cast.

```
'RESULT' = 
           case when (
          select sum( 
                          case when len(c.answer_text1) <= 2 then   
                             cast(isnull(c.answer_text1,'0') as int) 
                          else 
                             0 
                          end 
                         ) + 
               sum( 
                           case when len(c.answer_text2) <= 2 then  
                              cast(isnull(c.answer_text2,'0') as int) 
                           else 
                              0 
                           end 
                          )
        from Answers c 
                   where c.idlocation=b.idlocation and c.question_number='05' 
        ) > 0   
           then 
                1 
           else 
                0 
           end
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: By the way, the query is not necessarily adding up "more questions" than you ask for. It's more likely that the values cast(isnull...) are being pre-computed, and only the ones your query specifies to add will be accumulated.

Comment: Hi @KyleHale, I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate result of how the SQL Server query processor/optimizer works. In my opinion, the SQL standard prohibits the calculation of SELECT list expressions before the rows that will contribute to the result set have been identified, but the optimizer considers plans that violate this prohibition.

What you're observing is an error in the evaluation of a SELECT list item on a row that is not in the result set of your query. While this shouldn't happen, it does, and it's somewhat understandable, because to protect against it in every situation would exclude many efficient query plans from consideration. The vast majority of SELECT expressions will never raise an error, regardless of data.

What you can do is try to protect against this with an additional CASE expression. To protect against strings with the '/' character, for example:

```
... SUM(CASE WHEN c.answer_text1 IS NOT NULL and c.answer_text1 NOT LIKE '%/%' THEN CAST(c.answer_text1 as int) ELSE 0 END)...
```

If you're using SQL Server 2012, you have a better option: TRY_CONVERT:

```
...SUM(COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(int,c.answer_text1),0)...
```

In your particular case, the overall database design is flawed, because numeric information should be stored in number-type columns. (This, of course, may not be your fault.) So redesign is an option, putting integer answers in integer-type columns and non-integer answer_text elsewhere. A compromise, if you can't redesign the tables, that I think will work, is to add a persisted computed column with value TRY_CONVERT(int,c.answer_text1) (or its best equivalent, based on what you know about the actual data in the table - perhaps the integer value of only columns containing no non-digit character and having length less than 9).

Comment: Rereading your question, perhaps an easier solution is SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN b.question_number <> '05' THEN 0 ELSE c.answer_text1 END,0)). As far as I know, SQL Server will never evaluate an expression in a CASE statement for which the corresponding WHEN condition is false.

Comment: Alternatively you can just use is_numeric(answer_text1) then answer_text1 else 0 where once CASE hits a TRUE value for a WHEN expression it exits.

Comment: Yes, ISNUMERIC (no underscore) is probably pretty safe here, though it's not without its faults, since it only guarantees that the value can be converted to *some* numeric type, not necessarily INT. For example, ISNUMERIC(',') evaluates to 1, yet CAST(',' AS INT) fails.

Comment: Hi @SteveKass. This is a legacy system that is in production right now and needs some modifications, so the like filter works well and is practical to implement. What I am not sure I understand is if the execution planner raises the error because its choosing the most efficient plan to perform the task and that includes to ignore the filter before doing anything else?. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your query appears correct enough, which means you have a Question 05 record with a datetime in either the `answer_text1` or `answer_text2` field.

Give this a shot to figure out which row has a date:

```
select *
from Answers 
where question_number='05'
  and (isdate(answer_text1) = 1 or isdate(answer_text2) = 1)
```

Furthermore, you could filter out any rows that have dates in them

```
where isdate(c.answer_text1) = 0
  and isdate(c.answer_text2) = 0
  and ...
```

Comment: It's possible that there are no rows with question_number '05' that are not valid integer strings. (See my answer.) Also, ISDATE is not great for this task. It will return 1 for integer strings like '2011', but it will return 0 on a US-locale system for the string the OP mentioned: '27/12/2013'

Answer (score 1):

Another option similar in nature to Steve's excellent answer is to filter your Answers table with a subquery like so:

```
select
        l.idlocation,    

        'RESULT' = (
                      case when (
                        select 
                        sum(cast(isnull(c.answer_text1,0) as int)) +
                        sum(cast(isnull(c.answer_text2,0) as int)) 
                        from (select answer_text1, answer_text2, idlocation from Answers where question_number ='05') c
                        where b.idlocation=c.idlocation
                      ) > 0 then
                                   1
                      else 
                                   0
                      end
                    ) 

        from Locations l, Answers b
        where l.idlocation=b.idlocation and b.question_number='05'
```

More generally, though, you could just have this query like this

```
select locations.idlocation, case when sum(case when is_numeric(answer_text1) then answer_text1 else 0 end) + sum(case when is_numeric(answer_text2) then answer_text2 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as RESULT  from locations
inner join answers on answers.idlocation = locations.idlocation
where answers.question_number ='05'
group by locations.idlocation
```

Which would produce the same result.

Comment: Kyle, In my experience, the query processor may still produce a problematic execution plan with your first query. There's no way to demand that the query processor materialize a subquery. Remember that SQL is not an imperative language. A SQL statement simply describes a desired result. If there is a way to get it that doesn't decompose the steps in the way the user's query is written to suggest, it may still be considered.